# Sum function inside a do while loop not counting as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I've put a breakpoint on the `i = i+1` line. The code is counting fine. I added the `sh2.cells(1,3:4:5)` to see what's going wrong. 4 and 5 are showing me that `sum` and `sum2` are 0 even while `i` keeps counting. I've checked the formatting on the sheets to see if the brand codes were entered wrong. They are all right though.

Thoughts?

```
'Counts Cells
i = 5
j = 9

'Sum Product cell
sum = 0
sum2 = 0

'counts number of the brand
ct1 = 1
ct2 = 1

Do While sh1.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" 'cell need not be blank
  sh2.Cells(1, 3).Value = i
  sh2.Cells(1, 4).Value = sum
  sh2.Cells(1, 5).Value = sum2

  If sh1.Cells(i, j).Value = sh2.Cells(9, 5).Value Then 'cells(9,5) is brand 1
    sum = sum + sh1.Cells(i, j + 2).Value
    ct1 = ct1 + 1
  End If

  If sh1.Cells(i, j).Value = sh2.Cells(9, 6).Value Then 'Cells(9,6) is brand 2
    sum2 = sum2 + sh1.Cells(i, j).Value
    ct2 = ct2 + 1
  End If

  i = i + 1
Loop

sh2.Cells(10, 5).Value = sum / ct1
sh2.Cells(10, 6).Value = sum2 / ct2
```

Comment: You never change `j`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. This code is something I have to run for multiple lines. For this section, j won't change, but later on it will.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about what exactly is going wrong. Pleas tell us what you are expecting, and what is happening instead.

Comment: If you place a break point on the two `sum =` lines do you ever hit it?  My guess is that your value comparison is never equal so you never change the sum but it's too hard to tell without seeing the values.